# Button ID as getElementById

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

Can I get in "getElementById" the button ID value, which triggered the function?

I am trying to write a universal function where getElementById should be the same as button ID, so triggering function with a button which has different button ID results in different getElementById...

HTML:

```
<button id="10" onclick="f001()">C</button> 
<textarea id="11" rows="1" cols="25">Test123 </textarea> 

<button id="15" onclick="f001()">C</button> 
<textarea id="16" rows="1" cols="25">Test456 </textarea>
```

JS:

```
    function f001() {
    var copyText = document.getElementById("triggering button id + 1");
    copyText.select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
}
```

So I could have only 1 universal function with whom I could copy from various textareas...

Comment: This sounds like you have multiple elements with the same `id`, which is invalid html: an `id` is a unique identifier for an element within the document. Could you please share your relevant "*[mcve]*" code, including html and JavaScript?

Comment: you mean I can't have same id as button and same id as textarea id? It's different element...

Comment: Yes. An `id` must be unique within the document. You can use custom [`data-*` attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*) to link the elements, if necessary, or class-names. But since you're not sharing your code we can't offer any help, and will likely close the question as sharing the "*[mcve]*" code is a requirement.

Comment: Are you aware of the difference between event handlers which are assigned like you have shown here, and those which are assigned through the use of `.addEventListener`?
Going on the html you've shown, the textarea is the next child of the element that contains both the button and the textarea. When inside the code of a handler connected via `.addEventListener`, the `this` reserved word points to the button. You can ask for the next-sibling of any other element. `this.nextSibling` would do it. I'll write an answer shortly.

Comment: You're using the onclick event to call your function, the click event has a property that tells you the object that was clicked, unless you need to hard code the button name in your function, you probably would better off using the event.target, see https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_target.asp

Comment: You **can** use duplicate id values (if you should is another answer), only restriction is getElementById will only get you the **first** one. **And** Global variables with the same name as id are created! In FireFox it will point to that first element. In Chromium... tada.. you get an HTMLCollection of **all** elements with the same id. Is a remnant from early IE versions, when Microsoft owned the Browser market, and all vendors had to implement it or sites wouldn't run.

Comment: Note, ``querySelectorAll("#foo")`` returns a NodeList in all Browsers with **all** elements with the same id:foo. Since ``id`` can be called with ``element.id`` instead of longer getAttribute syntax or used in short CSS selectors, there are use cases for using duplicate ``id``s over classes or attributes. You just can't use ``getElementById``

Answer (score 1):

One approach to the solution, based on the code you've shared, is as follows:

```js
// defining the function along with an argument that represents
// the element that was clicked:
function f001(_elem) {

  // here we use the HTMLElement.id property to retrieve the
  // value of the 'id' attribute/property of the clicked
  // element and use parseInt() - along with the radix of 10 -
  // to convert that id into a number:
  var integer = parseInt(_elem.id, 10),
      // here we use document.getElementById() to find the
      // element with an id equal to the integer after it's
      // been incremented by 1:
      copyText = document.getElementById(++integer);

  // we select the entered value from that identified
  // element:
  copyText.select();

  // and execute the 'copy' action to assign the content
  // to the clipboard:
  document.execCommand("copy");
}
```

```html
<div>
  <!-- here we add the 'this' keyword to the function-call,
       this will be accessed in the function in order to
       retrieve the necessary properties of the element. We
       could pass 'this.id' to get direct access to the
       element's id, but that approach may limit us in future.  -->
  <button id="10" onclick="f001(this)">C</button>
  <textarea id="11" rows="1" cols="25">Test123 </textarea>

  <button id="15" onclick="f001(this)">C</button>
  <textarea id="16" rows="1" cols="25">Test456 </textarea>
</div>

<!-- a generic <textarea> into which the clipboard content
     may be pasted in order to demonstrate the success of
     the earlier function: -->
<div>
  <textarea placeholder="paste copied content here to check."></textarea>
</div>
```

Now, the reasons we *should not* use the above approach:

1. it requires us to reliably find all function-calls in the HTML when we update the requirements of the function, this causes
2. increased maintenance complexity in future (you might be the one that has to maintain the function/page, don't make your life harder).

What we can do instead is:

1. rely on `EventTarget.addEventListener()`, which uses JavaScript to bind the event-handling,
2. use a meaningful name for the function in order to more easily remember what the function does, and why it exists,
3. if we know that the DOM will remain in that manner then we can take advantage of that, especially if the `<textarea>` to be copied is always the `nextElementSibling` of the `<button>`.

With those improvements – though, admittedly, they may be opinion-based and personal preference – we can use the following:

```js
// defining the function along with a meaningful name, also takes an
// argument passed automatically from the later use of
// EventTarget.addEventListener():
const copyText = function(evt) {

    // from the Event Object passed in from EventTarget.addEventListener()
    // we retrieve the Event.currentTarget element, which is the element
    // to which the function is bound as the event-handler (Event.target
    // could be used instead, currently, unless other HTML elements were
    // placed within the <button> for styling purposes):
    var activated = evt.currentTarget,
    
        // we know that the <textarea> is the nextElementSibling, so here
        // we access that property of the HTMLElement:
        textarea = activated.nextElementSibling;

    // we select the entered-value:
    textarea.select();
    // we copy the entered-value to the clipboard:
    document.execCommand("copy");
  },
  
  // we find the <button> elements in the document:
  buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');

// we use NodeList.prototype.forEach() to iterate over the
// NodeList, using an Arrow function inside:
buttons.forEach(
  // here 'btn' is a reference to the current Node of the
  // NodeList over which we're iterating, and we use the
  // EventTarget.addEventListener() method to bind the
  // named - copyText() function, but note the deliberate
  // lack of parentheses - as the 'click' event-handler:
  (btn) => btn.addEventListener('click', copyText)
)
```

```html
<div>
  <button>C</button>
  <textarea>Test123 </textarea>

  <button>C</button>
  <textarea>Test456 </textarea>
</div>

<!-- a generic <textarea> into which the clipboard content
     may be pasted in order to demonstrate the success of
     the earlier function: -->
<div>
  <textarea placeholder="paste copied content here to check."></textarea>
</div>
```

We could also use custom `data-*` attributes to retrieve a property from the `<button>` elements via which we could retrieve the relevant `<textarea>`:

```js
// defining the function along with a meaningful name, also takes an
// argument passed automatically from the later use of
// EventTarget.addEventListener():
const copyText = function(evt) {

    // from the Event Object passed in from EventTarget.addEventListener()
    // we retrieve the Event.currentTarget element, which is the element
    // to which the function is bound as the event-handler:
    var activated = evt.currentTarget,
    
        // we then use the Element.dataset API to retrieve the attribute-value
        // of the data-copyfrom attribute:
        identifierString = activated.dataset.copyfrom,
        
        // we use a CSS attribute-selector, along with a Template Literal
        // (a String delimited using back-ticks) in which JavaScript can
        // be directly interpolated when wrapped with `${...JavaScript}`:
        textarea = document.querySelector( `[data-identifier=${identifierString}]` );

    // we select the entered-value:
    textarea.select();
    // we copy the entered-value to the clipboard:
    document.execCommand("copy");
  },
  
  // we find the <button> elements in the document with a custom data-copyfrom
  // attribute:
  buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button[data-copyfrom]');

// we use NodeList.prototype.forEach() to iterate over the
// NodeList, using an Arrow function inside:
buttons.forEach(
  // here 'btn' is a reference to the current Node of the
  // NodeList over which we're iterating, and we use the
  // EventTarget.addEventListener() method to bind the
  // named - copyText() function, but note the deliberate
  // lack of parentheses - as the 'click' event-handler:
  (btn) => btn.addEventListener('click', copyText)
)
```

```html
<div>
  <!-- using data-copyfrom to specify a value by which the
       the relevant <textarea> might be retrieved (this
       could identify a class-name, the element's id or any
       other unique custom data-* attribute-value: -->
  <button data-copyfrom="textareaOne">C</button>
  <!-- here we use the data-identifier custom attribute
       as the attribute, the value of which, will identify
       the relevant element: -->
  <textarea data-identifier="textareaOne">Test123 </textarea>

  <button data-copyfrom="textareaTwo">C</button>
  <textarea data-identifier="textareaTwo">Test456 </textarea>
</div>

<!-- a generic <textarea> into which the clipboard content
     may be pasted in order to demonstrate the success of
     the earlier function: -->
<div>
  <textarea placeholder="paste copied content here to check."></textarea>
</div>
```

References:

- CSS:

  - [Attribute-selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors).
- HTML:

  - [`data-*` attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*).
- JavaScript:

  - [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).
  - [`document.execCommand()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand).
  - [`document.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById).
  - [document.querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).
  - [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).
  - [`Event`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event).
  - [`Event.currentTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget).
  - [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).
  - [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).
  - [Increment operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Increment).

Answer (score 0):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
"use strict";
window.addEventListener('load', onLoaded, false);

// called when the window has finished loading
// - attaches a click handler to all buttons.
//   buttons are selected with the css selector 'button'
//   'button.someClass' would select all 'button' elements
//   that had the class 'someClass'
function onLoaded(evt)
{
    let buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');

// this code just does the same thing as the line below
//  buttons.forEach( 
//          function(btn)
//          { 
//              btn.addEventListener('click', onCopyBtnClick, false); 
//          } 
//      );
        
    buttons.forEach( btn => btn.addEventListener('click', onCopyBtnClick, false) );
}

function onCopyBtnClick(evt)
{
    // get reference to btn that fired the event
    let btn = this;

    // the textarea may not be the element immediately following
    // the button. In the code below, there's actually a 
    // text-node between the two walk through the list of 
    // siblings until we get to the first text-area after the button.
    let tmp = btn.nextSibling;
    while (tmp.nodeName != 'TEXTAREA')
        tmp = tmp.nextSibling;
    let targetTextarea = tmp;

    // select and copy the text
    targetTextarea.select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <button>COPY</button>
    <textarea rows='1' cols='25'>Test123 </textarea>
    
    <button>COPY</button>
    <textarea rows='1' cols='25'>Test456 </textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

### Example

```js
"use strict";
window.addEventListener('load', onLoaded, false);

// called when the window has finished loading
// - attaches a click handler to all buttons.
//   buttons are selected with the css selector 'button'
//   'button.someClass' would select all 'button' elements
//   that had the class 'someClass'
function onLoaded(evt)
{
    let buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');

// this code just does the same thing as the line below
//  buttons.forEach( 
//          function(btn)
//          { 
//              btn.addEventListener('click', onCopyBtnClick, false); 
//          } 
//      );
        
    buttons.forEach( btn => btn.addEventListener('click', onCopyBtnClick, false) );
}

function onCopyBtnClick(evt)
{
    // get reference to btn that fired the event
    let btn = this;

    // the textarea may not be the element immediately following
    // the button. In the code below, there's actually a 
    // text-node between the two walk through the list of 
    // siblings until we get to the first text-area after the button.
    let tmp = btn.nextSibling;
    while (tmp.nodeName != 'TEXTAREA')
        tmp = tmp.nextSibling;
    let targetTextarea = tmp;

    // select and copy the text
    targetTextarea.select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
}
```

```html
    <button>COPY</button>
    <textarea rows='1' cols='25'>Test123 </textarea>
    
    <button>COPY</button>
    <textarea rows='1' cols='25'>Test456 </textarea>
```

Comment: Thank you for answer and explanation, very usefull for beginner like me :)

Answer (score 0):

In Modern Browsers (anything but IE)
you can use W3C standard Custom Elements to create your own HTML tag:

```html
<my-textarea>Hello World!</my-textarea>
<hr>
<my-textarea>Hello Another World!</my-textarea>

<script>
  customElements.define("my-textarea", class extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback() {
      setTimeout(() => { //required because can only READ innerHTML after DOM is ready
        let textarea = document.createElement("textarea");
        let button = document.createElement("button");
        button.innerHTML = "copy me";
        button.id = "foo"; // no id needed, just showing wath duplicate ids do
        button.onclick = (evt) => { // inline event just fine, we're not attaching more
          textarea.select(); // in scope, so no need to search for textarea
          document.execCommand("copy");
          console.log(button.id, window[button.id]); // see difference in FireFox & Chrome
          console.log(document.querySelectorAll("#foo"));
        }
        textarea.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
        this.innerHTML = "";
        this.append(textarea, button); // learn the difference with appendChild
      })
    }
  })
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
"use strict";
window.addEventListener('load', onLoaded, false);

// called when the window has finished loading
// - attaches a click handler to all buttons.
//   buttons are selected with the css selector 'button'
//   'button.someClass' would select all 'button' elements
//   that had the class 'someClass'
function onLoaded(evt)
{
    let buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');

// this code just does the same thing as the line below
//  buttons.forEach( 
//          function(btn)
//          { 
//              btn.addEventListener('click', onCopyBtnClick, false); 
//          } 
//      );
        
    buttons.forEach( btn => btn.addEventListener('click', onCopyBtnClick, false) );
}

function onCopyBtnClick(evt)
{
    // get reference to btn that fired the event
    let btn = this;

    // the textarea may not be the element immediately following
    // the button. In the code below, there's actually a 
    // text-node between the two walk through the list of 
    // siblings until we get to the first text-area after the button.
    let tmp = btn.nextSibling;
    while (tmp.nodeName != 'TEXTAREA')
        tmp = tmp.nextSibling;
    let targetTextarea = tmp;

    // select and copy the text
    targetTextarea.select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
}
```

```html
    <button>COPY</button>
    <textarea rows='1' cols='25'>Test123 </textarea>
    
    <button>COPY</button>
    <textarea rows='1' cols='25'>Test456 </textarea>
```